# Updating a .csv file

Tags: python, python-2.x, csv, hash-map

I have a CSV file, call it csv_file. It has the following content:

```
Username, Password
name1, pass1
name2, pass2
...
```

I also have a dictionary, call it `mydict`. It has the following content:

```
mydict = {
    "name2" : "pass2",
    "name3" : "pass3"
     ...
}
```

I want to update my CSV file to now include `name3, pass3`, since those aren't in the CSV file but they are in the dictionary.

What's the most efficient, pythonic way of doing this?

Right now, here's what I have, but I don't think it's very efficient:

```
with open(csv_file, 'rb') as infile, open(new_csv_file, 'wb') as outfile:

     r = csv.DictReader(infile)
     w = csv.DictWriter(outfile, r.fieldnames)
     w.writeheader()

     temp_dict = {row['Username'] : row['Password'] for row in r}

     for k in mydict:
          if k.key not in temp_dict:
               temp_dict[k] = mydict[k]

     for value in temp_dict:
          w.writerow({'Username' : value, 'Password' : temp_dict[value]})
```

I'm sure there's something I can do to make this better. Any suggestions?

Comment: It seems like you aren't updating the file. You're reading one file and writing to another.

Comment: Yeah, that is true. I then later refer to the `new_csv_file` or I can replace the old one. But I haven't decided what I'll do at that point yet.

Comment: More efficient in what sense? Faster, use less memory, or what?

Comment: Does order matter (because it's going to be changed by converting the original file into a dictionary)?

Comment: Are you sure you only want to add new users from `mydict` but not update the password of any existing ones?

Comment: Assuming you don't want to update any existing passwords, you can update mydict with temp_dict. mydict.update(temp_dict). This will give the existing data priority. If you do want to update existing passwords, just switch the positions.

Comment: @martineau, preferably faster. Using less memory is also a plus, but not the main concern. The passwords aren't actually passwords, so they don't need to be updated, I was just giving an example. And thanks for pointing out the syntax; would the following be correct syntax, then: `w.writerow({'Username' : value, 'Password' : temp_dict[value]})`

Comment: @user3757614, thank you for that suggestion! I'll give it a shot!

Comment: Yes, that looks like valid syntax. What @user3757614 said is incorrect, `mydict.update(temp_dict)` doesn't give existing data "priority". It will add new things and _update existing ones_. If that's what you want to do, it's faster than using the `for` loop you have, but doesn't give you the control to only add items that aren't already present.

Comment: @martineau Look again; I did it "backwards". I'm updating the new data with the existing data from the file. Data just in the existing csv or just in the new data will go through to the new file, and data in both will use the version from the existing file.

Comment: @user3757614: Oh, sorry, missed that detail. Fine then, as long as it's OK to change the contents of `my_dict`.

Comment: You are opening the file in binary mode fro writing

Comment: @user132250: Opening csv files in binary is [the proper way](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) to do it in Python 2.x, but in Python 3.x text mode plus `newline-''` is what is suggested — see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv).

Answer (score 7):

There's no better way than creating a temporary dictionary to quickly update the contents of the entire file the way you want. However you can speed things by not using `csv.DictReader` and `csv.DictWriter` because they require building a separate temporary dictionary for each row processed.

Here's a more efficient version based on that supposition that also effectively updates the file "in-place". Note that the order of the rows in the file will be changed as a result of storing them temporarily in the dictionary. If that's important, use a [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead.

Also noteworthy is that it would be even more efficient to use @user3757614's suggestion, and instead do a less complicated `mydict.update(temp_dict)` (and then write `mydict.items()` out as the updated version of the file). If you want to preserve `mydict`, just make a copy of it first and then update that with `temp_dict`'s contents.

```
import csv
import os

mydict = {
    "name2" : "pass2",
    "name3" : "pass3"
#     ...
}

csv_file = 'users.csv'  # file to be updated
tempfilename = os.path.splitext(csv_file)[0] + '.bak'
try:
    os.remove(tempfilename)  # delete any existing temp file
except OSError:
    pass
os.rename(csv_file, tempfilename)

# create a temporary dictionary from the input file
with open(tempfilename, mode='rb') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, skipinitialspace=True)
    header = next(reader)  # skip and save header
    temp_dict = {row[0]: row[1] for row in reader}

# only add items from my_dict that weren't already present
temp_dict.update({key: value for (key, value) in mydict.items()
                      if key not in temp_dict})

# create updated version of file
with open(csv_file, mode='wb') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerows(temp_dict.items())

os.remove(tempfilename)  # delete backed-up original
```

Comment: Very interesting! I like this a lot! However, could you explain the purpose of appending `'.bak'` to  `tempfilename`

Edit: Nevermind, I did some reading and understand the purpose. Thanks!

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please consider up-voting and possibly accepting it. See [_What should I do when someone answers my question?_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)